# IdealForms - javascript - post not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#invalid')
              .show()
              .toggleClass('valid', ! invalid)
              .text(invalid ? (invalid +' invalid fields') : 'All good!');
             if (!invalid) $.post('register.php', this.$form.serialize(), function(response) {  

      }, 'json');
          }
```

This is my post function under .When I click submit the text 'All Good' comes but the page doesn't refresh or post the details to the register.php page.

Comment: Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you debug this, what happens?  How have you confirmed that no POST request is being made?

Comment: The console is clear white.No errors.I have placed echos in register.php, they did not come.In addtition to it, I also added if($_POST['submit']) echo...; to check if the post was submitted and the echo never came up.

Comment: "clear white"?  What are you looking at?  Use a browser debugger (such as FireBug or Chrome tools) to check for errors.  You'd also use that to check for requests, such as an AJAX POST (probably on a "network tab" of some kind in the tool).  There you can check what the actual request to and response from the server is, instead of just assuming that everything is working.  Since your code doesn't actually *do* anything with the response, it's not clear how you are even determining that this doesn't work.

Comment: The code which I mentioned is the code that is supposed to send the post message to the given php file.I created a blank file and typed echo 'hi'; and the message never came so I am confirmed that the post data never got sent.And about the white console, I was looking at the javascript console in Chrome.And also OnSubmit gets called because the text All Good comes.

Comment: Define "the message never came."  Your JavaScript code doesn't *do anything* with the response from the server.  So it's *ignoring* any "message" returned from the server.  If you want to see what the actual request and response are, use your debugging tools.  You can't just assume that your code is correct and determine errors based on the observed behavior of the entire system.

Comment: Sorry for all the mess.Firebug shows that the POST is sent when I click the submit button.Something must be wrong with my php.

Comment: What does FireBug show is the response?  Is it the response you expect?  Again, and I can't stress this enough, your JavaScript code is *ignoring* the response.  So any observed result that "nothing happens" is entirely correct, you've designed it such that nothing would happen.

Comment: POST http://xacnr.com/default/secure/register.php 200 OK 765ms - this is expected but now I need to figure out whats wrong with my php.And the page not refreshing is normal when a submit button is clicked?I think though the post message is sent, the page does not refresh for my php script to take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding how AJAX works.  You're expecting the page to refresh, but the code you're using explicitly tells the page *not* to refresh.  First, there's this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This does exactly what it says, it prevents the default event.  Assuming this is on a form, it's explicitly preventing the form from submitting.  Then you have your AJAX request:

```
$.post('register.php', this.$form.serialize(), function(response) {  

}, 'json');
```

As you've confirmed in FireBug, this sends a `POST` request to the server.  But... you're not doing anything with the response.  Your function is empty:

```
function(response) {

}
```

So... what do you expect to happen?  An empty function... doesn't do anything.  You can confirm in FireBug whether the response is what you expect it to be, but that's an entirely separate issue.  Whatever the response is, whether it's correct or not, isn't going to display on the page if you don't actually display it.  Take a look at the examples in [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

The response is placed in the `$(".result")` element(s).  In this code they're displaying the response.  If you want to see the response, you have to display it somewhere as well.